# RIGHT function within an IF statement

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to create an `IF` condition using the `RIGHT` function. It would look up the 4 last digits within a cell and compare it to another cell, then perform actions if it's a match.

Here's a simplified version of the code. The action to be performed is to display the counter in a cell.

```vb
Public vCounter

Sub Counter()

vCounter = 0

Sheets.Add.Name = "Test"

'The cells the RIGHT function will operate from (A1, A2 and A3)
Sheets("Test").Range("A1") = "123"
Sheets("Test").Range("A2") = "456"
Sheets("Test").Range("A3") = "789"

'The cells the result of the RIGHT function will be compared to (B1, B2 and B3)
Sheets("Test").Range("B1") = "23"
Sheets("Test").Range("B2") = "456"
Sheets("Test").Range("B3") = "89"

'This cell (G3) shows the result of a RIGHT function, considering the
'last two digits in A1, as an experience; it works.
Sheets("Test").Range("G3") = Right(Sheets("Test").Cells(1, 1), 2)

For i = 1 To 3

'The RIGHT function considers the two last digits of, successively,
'A1, A2 and A3, and those are compared to, respectively, 
'B1, B2 and B3. For some reason, it doesn't work here.
    If Right(Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 1), 2) = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 2) Then
        vCounter = vCounter + 1
    End If
Next i

'This cell (E3) shows the counter, to test whether or not the If
'condition with the RIGHT function works. By changing the contents
'of the cells I compare between each other, I can check whether or
'not it counts correctly. 
Sheets("Test").Range("E3") = vCounter

End Sub
```

What I get:

[image: current output]

The `RIGHT` function somehow doesn't work since the `vCounter` doesn't get to 2. It stays at 0, showing it doesn't count at all.

I deduce from this result that the problem resides in the `IF` statement containing the `RIGHT` function. Maybe the For Loop has to do with it.

Comment: `Right()` will return a string value, but the value from ColB is being read as numeric a Double). The string "23" and the number 23 aren't the same.   Even though for some reason `? cstr("23")=cdbl(23)` in the Immediate pane produces `True`

Comment: @Tim Williams - Pls explain also why "Right$" works differently than "Right" in this code.

Comment: What happens when you use `TRIM()` with `RIGHT()`. For example `If Right(Trim(Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 1).Value2), 2) = Trim(Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 2).Value2) Then`

Comment: @dcromley - I had to look it up but seems like Right() returns a Variant(string) type but Right$() returns a String.

Comment: You will get what you want if you force reading the cell content as text by modifying the `If` line as `If Right(Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 1).Text, 2) = Sheets("Test").Cells(i, 2).Text Then`. As `Right` anyway returns text, `Text` addition is not strictly necessary for the left side of the comparison.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams, as well as Siddharth Rout and Tom Brunberg. The fact RIGHT() returns a string value was definitely the reason. I was confused because the cell format for G3 was still displaying "General". I guess cell format and value type are different things. I fixed the issue by putting the RIGHT() result in a CSng() function, and it works. Tim, could you propose your first comment as an answer so that I can declare this question as solved? If it is possible to select multiple answers and Siddharth and Tom propose their comments as answers, I'll accept them too.

Comment: `RIGHT()` returns a `Variant(string)` type and `RIGHT$()` returns a `String`. Technically `RIGHT$()` is more efficient than `RIGHT()` but the difference is hardly noticable. The main difference between them is that the ones with the `$` cannot handle `Null` values. Personally I do not use the one with `$`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're writing string values to your sheet, Excel will automatically assume them to be numeric values, so when you read them back you will be getting values of type `Variant/Double`.

If you pass one of those Doubles through `Right()` though, it will return a `Variant\String`, and it's that comparison between Variant\String and Variant\Double which seems to be failing.

Some test code:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, v As Variant
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "123"
    ws.Range("B1").Value = "23"
    
    'Comparing values...
    Debug.Print Right(ws.Range("A1").Value, 2) = ws.Range("B1").Value '>> False (Variant\String vs Variant\Double)
    
    Debug.Print Right(ws.Range("A1").Value, 2) = CStr(ws.Range("B1")) '>> True (Variant\String vs Variant\String)
    
End Sub
```